# SQL query based on subquery. Retrieve transactions with data > threshold

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, subquery, conditional-statements

My db table is called transactions and is like this:

```
 Name |    Date (DateTime)   | Type |  Stock    | Volume | Price | Total
 Tom    2014-05-24 12:00:00    Sell   Barclays     100      2.2     220.0
 Bob    2014-04-13 15:00:00    Buy    Coca-Cola    10       12.0    120.0

varchar    DateTime           varchar varchar      int      float   float
```

My initial problem was to remove from the table ALL the transactions that belong to a user whose first transaction is later than a certain threshold.
My query was:

```
DELETE FROM transactions WHERE name NOT IN (SELECT name FROM transactions2 WHERE date < CAST('2014-01-01 12:00:00.000' as DateTime));
Query OK, 35850 rows affected (3 hours 5 min 28.88 sec)
```

I think this is a poor solution, I had to duplicate the table to avoid deleting from the same table from where I am reading, and the execution took quite a long time (3 hours for a table containing ~170k rows)

Now I am trying to delete ALL the transactions that belong to a user whose latest transaction happened before a certain threshold date.

```
DELETE FROM transactions WHERE name IN (SELECT name FROM transactions HAVING max(date) < CAST('2015-01-01 12:00:00.000' as DateTime) );
```

Sadly, the subquery finds only one result:

```
SELECT name FROM transactions HAVING max(date) < CAST('2015-01-01 12:00:00.000' as DateTime)';

+------------+
| name       |
+------------+
| david      |
+------------+
```

I guess I am getting only one result because of the max() function.
I am not an expert of SQL but I understand quite well what I need in terms of sets and logic. 
I would be really happy to have suggestions on how to rewrite my query.

EDIT:
Here is a sqlfiddle with the schema and some data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/389ede/2

I need to remove ALL the entries for alex, because his last transactions happened before a certain threshold (let's say 1 Jan 2013).
Don't need to delete tom's transactions because he has his latest later than 1 Jan 2013.

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET.

Comment: right, edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first query can be formulated as: `delete users from transactions where it does not exist a transaction for that user before ?. This is easy to transform to sql:

```
delete from transactions t1
where not exists (
    select 1 from transactions t2
    where t1.name = t2.name
      and t2.date < ?
)
```

mysql still does not support (AFAIK) deleting from a table that is referenced in a select, so we need to rewrite it as:

```
delete t1.* 
from transactions t1
left join transactions t2
    on t1.name = t2.name
   and t2.date < ?
where t2.name is null
```

date is a reserved word so you will have to quote that.

Your second query can be solved the same way, delete from transaction where it does not exists a transaction after a certain date. I'll leave it as an exercise.

Comment: Given your sample data in the fiddle all users have transactions before '2014-01-01 12:00:00.000' so no row should be deleted according to your wording of the query. If you disagree, what rows from the fiddle should be deleted and why?

Comment: I am sorry, I rushed on sqlfiddle with 2012-01-01 as date, and changed the delete in select so I was a bit confused. your solution works as a charm and I am trying to use it also for the second part of my question. It is still running so I have no results yet.
Can you please give a bit of explanation for the second version?

Comment: If the latest transaction happened before a certain point in time, it means that it does not exists transactions for that user after that time. I.e. t2.date > ?, did that clarify?

Comment: date is not a reserved word

Comment: What part of the query is actually referencing the "latest"?
And what does this part do "where t2.name is null"?

Comment: @AlvinPastore - you've just answered your own question ;-)

Comment: Lennart, sorry for re-opening the issue but I think you can help me clarify something.

In this sqlfiddle I have a simplified version of my question (using int value instead of date). I used your solution and it works in both cases (selecting/deleting players that started having transactions too late or whose last transaction is too old)
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b88ab2/2

When I try to do the same to my table, using the datatime it does not give any row as result. As shown in this sqlfiddle
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/753cd/2

Is it a problem with the date format?

Comment: Alvin, I'll add another answer and hopefully that will clear things up.

Answer (score 1):

Alvin here is a simplified scenario from your fiddle with dates:

```
CREATE TABLE transactions 
(    id    int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
,    name  varchar(30) NOT NULL
,    value datetime NOT NULL
,       PRIMARY KEY (id) ) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO transactions (name, value) VALUES ('alex',  '2011-01-01 12:00:00')
                                           ,  ('alex',  '2012-06-01 12:00:00');
```

Let's investigate what happens in:

```
SELECT t1.name as t1_name, t1.value as t1_value
     , t2.name as t2_name, t2.values as t2_value
FROM transactions t1
LEFT JOIN transactions t2
    ON t1.name = t2.name

T1_NAME     T1_VALUE    T2_NAME     T2_VALUE
alex    January, 01 2011 12:00:00+0000  alex    January, 01 2011 12:00:00+0000
alex    January, 01 2011 12:00:00+0000  alex    June, 01 2012 12:00:00+0000
alex    June, 01 2012 12:00:00+0000     alex    January, 01 2011 12:00:00+0000
alex    June, 01 2012 12:00:00+0000     alex    June, 01 2012 12:00:00+0000
```

I.e. 4 rows. If we now add the join predicate:

```
SELECT t1.name as t1_name, t1.value as t1_value
     , t2.name as t2_name, t2.values as t2_value
FROM transactions t1
LEFT JOIN transactions t2
    ON t1.name = t2.name    
   AND t2.value > CAST('2011-06-01 12:00.000' as DateTime)
```

This leaves us with two rows. If we change the time to '2012-06-01 12:00.000' we still have two rows due to the left join, but the t2 columns will be null.

If we now add the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT t1.name as t1_name, t1.value as t1_value
     , t2.name as t2_name, t2.values as t2_value
FROM transactions t1
LEFT JOIN transactions t2
    ON t1.name = t2.name    
   AND t2.value > CAST('2012-06-01 12:00.000' as DateTime)
WHERE t2.name is null;
```

we still have two rows. With CAST('2011-06-01 12:00.000' as DateTime) there are no rows.

Remember that the construction is equivalent with:

```
SELECT t1.name as t1_name, t1.value as t1_value
FROM transactions t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM transactions t2
    WHERE t1.name = t2.name    
      AND t2.value > CAST('2012-06-01 12:00.000' as DateTime)
);
```

So, if it does not exist a row for the name where value > '2012-06-01 12:00.000' we have a match. Does that clarify?

Answer (score 0):

@Lennart, Alvin, consider the following...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,val INT NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO my_table (val) VALUES (1),(1),(2),(1),(3),(2),(3),(1),(4);

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+----+-----+
| id | val |
+----+-----+
|  1 |   1 |
|  2 |   1 |
|  3 |   2 |
|  4 |   1 |
|  5 |   3 |
|  6 |   2 |
|  7 |   3 |
|  8 |   1 |
|  9 |   4 |
+----+-----+
```

Let's delete the most recent result for each `val`, i.e. the result of...

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT val, max(id) max_id FROM my_table GROUP BY val ) y 
    ON y.val = x.val 
   AND y.max_id = x.id;
+----+-----+
| id | val |
+----+-----+
|  8 |   1 |
|  6 |   2 |
|  7 |   3 |
|  9 |   4 |
+----+-----+
```

So...

```
DELETE x 
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN ( SELECT val, max(id) max_id FROM my_table GROUP BY val ) y 
    ON y.val = x.val 
   AND y.max_id = x.id;

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+----+-----+
| id | val |
+----+-----+
|  1 |   1 |
|  2 |   1 |
|  3 |   2 |
|  4 |   1 |
|  5 |   3 |
+----+-----+
```

Comment: Isn't this considering data insertion time as criteria?
While in my solution I have dates that do not correspond to the date of insertion.

Comment: I'm just demonstrating a principle.

Comment: Ok I played a bit and I think I got it thank you both! very helpful!! @Lennart