# Mysql error:1093 - Can't specify target table for update in FROM clause

Tags: mysql, subquery, mysql-error-1093

I have a table employees in my database with corrupt entries.

I tried to delete them excuting:

```
delete from employees 
where id_boss= (
select id_worker from employees e
where surname= 'XXX')
AND basic_wage>1500
```

but I get the next error:

> **#1093 - You can't specify target table 'pracownicy' for update in FROM clause**

How can I overcome this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL query based on subquery. Retrieve transactions with data > threshold](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23935467/sql-query-based-on-subquery-retrieve-transactions-with-data-threshold)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL you can't delete from a row where you are selecting from at the same time. To overcome this you can either use another subquery to hide this fact or you can turn this into a join like this

```
delete e_emp
from employees e_emp
join employees e_boss on e_boss.id_worker = e_emp.id_boss 
where e_boss.surname = 'XXX'
AND e_emp.basic_wage > 1500
```

Answer (score 0):

It also correctly? 
because it works

```
DELETE e_emp FROM  employees e_emp, 
(SELECT id_boss FROM employees  WHERE surname='XXX') AS e_boss
WHERE e_emp.id_boss=e_boss.id_worker
AND e_emp.basic_wage>1500
```